# Calculating cross terms for Haven coefficient using windowed MSD

Tags: computational-physics, software, diffusion, molecular-dynamics

My problem is that from this site: [MSD Module](https://freud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/msd.html) I'm taking an equation that expresses the windowed mean squared displacement (MSD):

$$MSD(m) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{1}{N-m}\sum_{k=0}^{N-m-1}(\overline{r_i}(k+m)-\overline{r_i}(k))^2$$

And I understand everything up until I need to calculate charge diffusion coefficient in order to obtain Haven ratio which is defined as $H_R = D^*/D_\sigma$ where $D^*$ is tracer diffusion and $D_\sigma$ is charge diffusion. From this article: [From ionic to superionic conductivity: The influence of cation order on
sodium diffusion in Na3Zr2Si2PO12](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ssi.2021.115604) I took equations that describe these two coefficients in different ways:

$$D^*=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}R_i(t)^2$$

and

$$D_\sigma = \frac{1}{N}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{N}R_i(t)\right]^2$$

And I know how to apply first $MSD(m)$ equation for $D^*$ coefficient but I have no clue how to apply it to $D_\sigma$. I see the difference in this equations where it is explained for example in this [article](https://doi.org/10.1088/0965-0393/21/7/074003), where it states that

> In fact, for the calculation of $D$, one has to calculate the displacements of the individual ions at a certain time $t$ and, then, take the average of these. On the other hand, when calculating $Deff$, one does not average over the individual displacements but simply sums them up.

But I dont know how to apply it for WINDOWED MSD. Can anyone help me and tell step by step how to do this?

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: Is $r(t)$ in your first equation different from the $R(t)$ in the latter two?

Comment: r(t) are position vectors for ions and R(t) is MSD (as it is said in the second article, it's sometimes also confusing to me what is what